# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier while working with JSON.

Tags: jquery, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var index = "index";
        var park = "park";

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                url="http://openAPI.seoul.go.kr:8088/personalKeyvalue/json/SearchParkInfoService/1/3"
                $.getJSON(url,function(result) {
                    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONObject jsonService = jsonRoot.getJSONObject("SearchParkInfoService");
                    int totalCount = jsonService.getInt("list_total_count");
                    JSONArray json = jsonService.getJSONArray("row");
                    for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                        document.write(json+"<br>");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Retrieve data from JSON with AJAX!</h2>
        <button>GetAJAX data</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in Google Chrome.

The error occurs on 14th line, which is:

```
JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(result);
```

Could you provide any suggestions to solve the problem, please?

Comment: What is `JSONObject`?  This is neither standard javascript nor jQuery afaik. Javascript would be `var jsonRoot = JSON.parse(result);` In javascript there is no other option of variable declaration than via the keyword `var`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not define variables like this in JavaScript:

```
JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(result);
```

because it is not a strongly-typed language. You would define this variable as such:

```
var jsonRoot = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: so i follow that solution, then a new problem is **Uncaught ReferenceError: JSONObject is not defined**

Comment: @user1838838 You don't define JSONObject anywhere in your code, so this is expected.

Comment: @MichaelMior Thx i add this '<sciprt src="json2.js"></script>' then it will be OK

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you got that code from, this is wrong. It is not valid javascript.

The only way how to declare a variable in javascript is via the keyword `var`.

Correct would be (edited after your comment):

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(result);
// now you can work with the json by retrieving the values in javascript fashion
// like this:
var jsonService = jsonObject["SearchParkInfoService"];
var totalCount  = jsonService["list_total_count"];
var row         = jsonService["row"];
```

This works assuming that your jsonObject looks like:

```
{
   SearchParkInfoService : {
        list_total_count : <value>,
        row              : [<arrayvalues>,...]
   },
}
```

Comment: yes my jsonObejct is this
{
    "SearchParkInfoService": {
        "list_total_count": 95,
        "row": [
            {
                "P_PARK": "초안산근린공원",
                "P_IMG": "http://parks.seoul.go.kr/upload/parks/1308025824989374000.JPG",
                "G_LONGITUDE": "203653.8950",
                "G_LATITUDE": "460875.1060",..............

so i want to take P_PARK / P_IMG / G_LONGITUDE / G_LATITUDE

Comment: im very sorry but `var jsonObject = new JSON.parse(result);` cause an error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o** however, i cant find any token o in there, everywhere...

Comment: @user1838838 omit that `new`, that was an accident...;) Is JSONObject defined in your `json2.js`? Then maybe you abstraction layer with `... = new JSONObject()` might work. Also take a look at my edited answer.